# TYPO3 Extbase JsonView FAL

Tags: json, controller, typo3, extbase

This is my Controller Action:

```
public function jsonAction()
{
    $this->view->setVariablesToRender(array('produkte'));
    $this->view->setConfiguration(
        array(
            'produkte' => array(
                '_descendAll' => array(
                    'only' => array('titel', 'beschreibung', 'bild', 'download', 'categories'),
                    '_descend' => array(
                        'bild' => array(),
                        'download' => array(),
                        'categories' => array(),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $this->view->assign('produkte', $this->produktRepository->findAll());
}
```

and I get a very nice JSON-String. Unfortunately I get only the PID und UID for contained files (FAL). How can I get the full object or at least the path to the contained files?

```
/**
 * Returns the bild
 *
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $bild
 */
public function getBild()
{
    return $this->bild;
}

/**
 * Returns the download
 *
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $download
 */
public function getDownload()
{
    return $this->download;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant model parts of Produkt?

Comment: ok, edit above. Hope it is the right part.

Comment: I suspect this has to to with the fact that properties of file and file reference objects are not real object properties, but are stored as lazily loaded associative array (named `properties`, I think). The `JsonView` handles only the ones it can get by calling `get_object_vars` (through the call to [getGettablePropertyNames()](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/_object_access_8php_source.html#l00232)), which uses `get_object_vars`. Try to output the property `properties`, maybe that helps? Not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try descending to the `originalResource` of the `FileReference` and expose `publicUrl`:

```
$this->view->setConfiguration(
    array(
        'produkte' => array(
            '_descendAll' => array(
                'only' => array('titel', 'beschreibung', 'bild', 'download', 'categories'),
                '_descend' => array(
                    'download' => array(
                        '_descendAll' => array(
                            '_only' => array('originalResource');
                            '_descend' => array(
                                'originalResource' => array(
                                    '_only' => array('publicUrl');
                                );
                            );
                        );
                    ),
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you, i try it. But unfortunately there is no effect. Only PID and UID.

Comment: Please do a `DebuggerUtility:var_dump` on a `Produkt` (maybe deactive JsonView for this purpose), e.g. debug the first item (`$this->produktRepository->findAll()->getFirst()`) and see if the property `originalResource` is working there

Answer (score 0):

The `originalResource` is partly a computed property, on invoking the getter-method the entity will be retrieved automatically - that's how it's implemented in Extbase's `FileReference` model.

```
/**
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference
 */
public function getOriginalResource()
{
    if ($this->originalResource === null) {
        $this->originalResource = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory::getInstance()->getFileReferenceObject($this->getUid());
    }

    return $this->originalResource;
}
```

However, please make sure to write the JSON view configuration correct. All control-related properties are prefixes with an underscore `_` - in the code examples above it should be `_only` instead of `only`. Valid control-names are `_only`, `_exclude`, `_descend`, `_descendAll`, `_exposeObjectIdentifier`, `_exposedObjectIdentifierKey`, `_exposeClassName`.

Find more details in the [Flow documentation](http://flowframework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/ModelViewController.html#json-view), which is still valid for the `JsonView` in TYPO3 CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference>* instead of *\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference* for your FAL properties in your Model.
I dont need more than one File, but after i changed this i get the publicUrl.